# Custom Analyzer not working Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

```
{
  "_source": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "default": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
        "filter": "lowercase,standard,stop"
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "table": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string",
          "include_in_all": false,
          "index": "no"
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "long",
          "include_in_all": false,
          "index": "no"
        },
        "field3": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed"
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The analyzer doesn't seem to work when testing it. The analyzer should not index stop words and it should also index an email address as a whole. When I "TEST ANALYZER" and type "Jack is fine", indexing of all three words takes place. I do not want it to index the stopwords in english language such as "and","is" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the fields to be "index": "no" and also disable `include_in_all`. How do you expect to have something put in the index? Quote from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#string):

> `no` means that it won’t be searchable at all (as an individual field; it may still be included in `_all`). Setting to `no` disables `include_in_all`.

And the actual `settings` should be like this (you are missing `"settings"` from your index definition):

```
{
  "_source": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": "lowercase,standard,stop"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "table": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string",
          "include_in_all": false,
          "index": "no"
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "long",
          "include_in_all": false,
          "index": "no"
        },
        "field3": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do have other fields in which the index is set to 'yes', just that I haven't shown those in this particular code snippet. I can show those if you want.

Comment: Share more than that, because the question is not completely clear. Share what have you tried (exact commands), what was the result and what was the expectation.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, so I  didn't know how much to explain. I have explained the problem further.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You are missing a key element in your index definition: the `settings`. Try my code and see if it works for you.